# SQL datetime column vs column for year, month and day

Tags: sql

If I create a table with data and a column for a timestamp and another table with data and three columns of integers for year, month and day then which table is better for space, speed and query simplicity?

Comment: That would probably depend on the DBMS you are using. Excuse me, but I couldn't find that detail in your question. I suggest that you add a tag for the DBMS you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL range of int Column range from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 which is 4 Bytes, while the Date column size is 3 Bytes.
In your case if you create 3 int columns it will occupy 12 Bytes where in Date column will occupy 3 Bytes.
Also, there are better Date functions which will ease up your work, to put in more detail, I've categorized your query in 3 sections

Space:

The table with a single column for a timestamp will likely take up less space than the table with three integer columns for year, month, and day since it only requires one column to store the same information.
However, if you only need to store dates and not times, using three integer columns for year, month, and day might be more space-efficient as each column could be stored as a single byte rather than eight bytes for a timestamp.

Speed:

Query speed will depend on how the data is indexed and the specific queries you plan to run.
If you frequently need to filter data by year, month, and day, using three integer columns might be faster since the values can be indexed separately.
On the other hand, if you need to perform calculations or aggregations on the timestamp data, using a single timestamp column might be faster since it can be indexed as a whole and can take advantage of built-in timestamp functions in the database.

Query Simplicity:

The table with a single timestamp column may be simpler to query for certain operations, such as finding the most recent data point or calculating the time between two data points.
However, if you need to perform calculations or aggregations based on year, month, and day, using three integer columns may be simpler since you won't need to extract these values from the timestamp column.
In summary, the best approach depends on the specific use case and the types of queries you plan to run. If you frequently need to filter data by year, month, and day, using three integer columns might be more efficient. However, if you need to perform calculations or aggregations on the timestamp data, using a single timestamp column might be faster and simpler.